# How to find the index of a row in a table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find the index of a row in a table. I'm trying to use the following code, but I seem to get an index of -1.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("tr").click(function (){
        var index = $("table").index($(this));
        $("span").text("That was row index #" + index);
    });
});
```

With html that looks like this;

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>click</td></tr>
    <tr><td>click</td></tr>
    <tr><td>click</td></tr>
    <tr><td>click</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks

Comment: var index = $(this).index();

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$("tr").index(this)
```

The documentation shows just passing this and that the preceding selection should be where the node is found. If you need to find it in a specific table (and there are multiple), you may need to provide some context:

```
// haven't tested this
$("tr", $(this).closest("table")).index(this)
```

Comment: From a child inside the row, $(this).closest("tr").index() does the trick. The second option in this answer doesn't work.

Comment: turns out `this` isnt necessary to be passed in the `index` function as it gave me -1 every time, using without `this` parameter works ok

Comment: Joshua's solution worked fine for me. I need to click a button from a TD.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
var index = $("table tr").index(this);
```

The documentation for `index()` says:

> Searches every matched element for the
>   object and returns the index of the
>   element, if found, starting with zero.
>   If a jQuery object is passed, only the
>   first element is checked.

You need to call the `index()` on a collection of `<tr>` elements, not the parent `<table>`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Getting -1 on everything though.

Comment: @stevek I edited the answer to remove the `$()` around `this`, since I'm not sure if jQuery would return the same object instance on calls to `$` with the same node instance.

Comment: you dont need to pass `this` as the parameter just remove it and use `.index()` it will work correctly @Winnemucca

Answer (score 3):

Based on Robs answer to find index in specific table, this worked for me.

```
var index = $('tr', $(this).closest("table")).index(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just found an interesting trick, which basically consists on counting the previous siblings:

```
var tr = $(some_selector);
var rowIndex = tr.prevAll().length;
```

This way you will get 0 if this is the first `tr`, 3 if this is the 4th `tr`, etc.

Just for the sake of it, another option using `index()`, which saves you from having to know how to select the containing table:

```
var rowIndex = tr.parent().children().index(tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the td object and its parent index is tr index

```
$(this).parent().index()
```