# Using JQuery to switch selected row of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table.  When a row is clicked on, it is given `.active` and the row is highlighted.  I need to work on other ways to change the selected row other than clicking on it.  For my example, I've chosen a next button.

http://jsfiddle.net/dHxKW/

I can do the logic behind what happens when it gets to the end of the table or anything else like that.

**I just need help figuring out how to get the index of the TR with class active** so that I can increase the index, which then I can give the next row the active class...   That's all I need to do... how to get that row index.

This is some of the stuff I've tried that doesn't work...

```
    alert( $('table tr .active').index() ); 

    var row = $('table tr.active').first(); 

    alert(row.index() );   

    alert($("table").index( $('table tr .active') ));
```

This is what I'm using as a reference (https://stackoverflow.com/a/469910/623952)

```
var index = $("table tr").index($(this));
```

but I can't get the selectors right...

**Solution.....**

it would have never worked... I wrote bad code:

`$(this).children("tr").addClass("active");`  (this = clicked on tr in the click function)

But new code: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dHxKW

```
 $("#table_one").on("click", "tr", function () {
     $(".active").removeClass("active");

     $(this).children("td").addClass("active");

     // removed line: $(this).children("tr").addClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
 });

 $('#btn_next').on('click', function () 
{ 
     // right here  ********** 

     var n = $('tr.active').next(); 

     $(".active").removeClass("active");     

     n.children("td").addClass("active");
     n.addClass("active");

 });
```

** Just as a note, I am adding the class to both the tr and td's... I'm not sure if this is the best way but tr doesn't have background properties, so I just added it to both.  I think this might be the reason for my confusion....

Comment: use .each and increment a counter

Comment: What about using .next() on the active tr ? And if it is null, parent().children(0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the "active" class is not being added to the "tr" elements.

In this line you are looking for `tr` children of `this`, but `this` is a `tr`, thus no children get selected: `$(this).children("tr").addClass("active");`

Instead try `$(this).addClass("active");`

Comment: can you put that on the fiddle?  i am trying to and it's still returning index of -1... i might be putting it somewhere bad or something.  just have the value returned in an alert for the btn_next click.

Comment: Had an error in my original answer... I updated my answer after I played a little on jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

```
$('td.active').parent().index('tr')
```

will get you the index.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dHxKW/2/)**

**[jsFiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dHxKW/3/)**

BTW, the link in your click function `$(this).children("tr").addClass("active");` would seem to do nothing as it searches for a child row of a row.

Answer (score 1):

```
var counter = 0;
var index = -1

$('table tr').each(function(){
    if( ! $(this).hasClass('active')) {
         counter++;
    }
    else index = counter;
})
```

Comment: Isn't this looking for tr.active elements INSIDE each selected tr ?

Comment: i think thats about right PSCoder but im sure there is a bug (as Im a bit pissed)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table tr .active').removeClass('active').parent().next().children('td').addClass('active');
```

this should do it

Comment: There is something wrong here, you remove the class to a tr and add it to a td.

Comment: no, i remove it from tr .active (which is td inside tr), not tr.active (which is null)

Comment: and how it will start as there is not tr initially have active class .