# Populate a Symfony form row with a table row index

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I'm facing a stupid issue there but I'm sure it would be easy for you, master of javascript !

Here is my symfony form :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('accept', 'checkbox', array('required' => false, 'label' => 'Do You Accept This News ?'))
            ->add('custom', 'textarea', array('required' => false, 'attr' => array('rows' => 10), 'label' => 'Attach a Custom Message'))
            ->add('line', 'integer', array('required' => false))
            ->add('Send', 'submit',array('attr' => array('class' => 'button')))
            ->getForm();
```

And here is my twig template rendering it :

```
<table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Statement</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% set count = 0 %}
        {% for milestone in milestones %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ milestone.createdAt | date('M-d H:i:s') }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ path('rudelist_entity',{'slug':milestone.idEntity.slug})}}">{{ milestone.idEntity.name}}</a>{{ newStatements[count] }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="button revealModal" href="#" data-reveal-id="myModalJournalist">Treat News</a>
                <div id="myModalJournalist" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>   
                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    <div class="marginBottom">
                        {{ form_widget(form.accept) }}
                        {{form_label(form.accept)}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldContainer fieldTextareaContainer">
                        {{form_label(form.custom)}}
                        {{form_widget(form.custom)}}
                        {{form_errors(form.custom)}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="hide">
                        {{form_widget(form.line)}}
                    </div>

                    {{ form_end(form) }}

                    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                </div>
        </tr>
        {% set count = count + 1 %}
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

So the thing is, I'm displaying a button for each row, but they all open the same modal with an unique form, in which I have a boolean, a textarea and an integer field which I'm hidding because I want to auto-fill the "line" row of my form with the index of the row of the button that was click, so I would know with row I need to update.
I've been trying that but unsuccessfully :

```
$(function(){
    $("body").on('click','a.button.revealModal',function(){
        var position = $(this).parents("tr").index();
        $("#form").find("input#form_line").val(position);
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Check Here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-t‌​able-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-t%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bable-using-jquery)
Have you tried:

```
$("tr").index(this)
```

The documentation shows just passing this and that the preceding selection should be where the node is found. If you need to find it in a specific table (and there are multiple), you may need to provide some context:

```
// haven't tested this
$("tr", $(this).closest("table")).index(this)
```