# Generate form from bootstrap table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

this is my [**plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/PWrq5wXZYheJQ4e2CuUX?p=preview). What I'm trying to do is when user click on row, he will see form on the bottom of page and could correct it. With using jquery .html() I've rendered lower table but how could I set input form for that?

this is my code:

```
$(function () {

   $("#button").click(function () {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable('refreshOptions', {
                data: data,
                detailView: false,
                filterControl: true,
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: 'name',
                        title: 'Name',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,
                        filterControl: 'input'
                    }, {
                        field: 'stargazers_count',
                        title: 'Structure',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,
                         filterControl: 'input'
                    }, {
                        field: 'forks_count',
                        title: 'Class',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,
                         filterControl: 'input'
                    }, {
                        field: 'description',
                        title: 'Description',
                        sortable: true,
                        editable: true,
                         filterControl: 'input'
                    }
                ]
            });
    });


    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
       detailView: true,
        formatNoMatches: function () {
            return "This table is empty...";
        },

         onClickCell: function(field, value, row, $element) {
                        if (field == 'name') {
                            $element.parent('tr').find('>td>.detail-icon').click();
                             // NOTE: needs index to call to expandRow
                             var $tr = $element.parent('tr');
                             // NOTE: literally first google result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery
                             var index = $("> tr",  $('#table').find('> tbody')).index($tr);
                             $('#table').bootstrapTable('expandRow',index);
                        }
                    },
      onExpandRow: function(index, row, $detail) {
      // console.log(row)
      $detail.html('<table></table>').find('table').bootstrapTable({
        columns: [{
          field: 'id',
          title: 'id'
        }, {
          field: 'status',
          title: 'stat'
        }, {
          field: 'date',
          title: 'date'
        }],
        data: row.children,
        // Simple contextual, assumes all entries have further nesting
        // Just shows example of how you might differentiate some rows, though also remember row class and similar possible flags
      });
}
});
});

$(function () {
    var $result = $('#form');
    $('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {

        $('.success').removeClass('success');
        $($element).addClass('success');
        function getSelectedRow() {
            var index = $('#table').find('tr.success').data('index');
            return $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index];
        }
        $result.html(
            '<table border="0" align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px; font-size: 14px; color: #0f0f0f">' + '<h3>'+
            '<tr  align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">' + '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Name</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' + '<td>' + getSelectedRow().name + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
            '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">' + '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Structure</td>'  + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().stargazers_count + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
            '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"> '+ '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Class</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().forks_count + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
            '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"> '+ '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Description</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().description + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
            '</h3>' + '</table>'
        );
    });
});
```

html

```
 <body>
    <h3>Click on row that to see results</h3>
<div id="toolbar">
  <button id="button" class="btn-primary btn">Load Table</button>
                        </div>
                        <table id="table"
                               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
                               data-search="true"
                               data-editable="false"
                               data-show-refresh="false"
                               data-show-toggle="false"
                               data-show-columns="true"
                               data-show-export="true"
                               data-detail-view="true"
                               data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
                               data-minimum-count-columns="2"
                               data-id-field="text"
                               data-response-handler="responseHandler"
                               data-field="operate"
                               data-events="operateEvents"
                               data-formatter="operateFormatter"
                               data-filter-control="true"
                               data-unique-id="id">
                        </table>
                        <div id="form"></div>
                          </body>
```

Comment: You fill your `$result` variable with the HTML you want but you never append it to any part of the DOM.

Comment: @RobertoLinares so it should be like $result.append.html {blah blah blah} or what?

Comment: You should first decide in what part of your HTML you want it appended. Ej, if you want it inside the `<div id="toolbar">`div, then you shoud do something like: `$("#toolbar").append($result)`

Comment: @RobertoLinares hold on, thru this line  var $result = $('#form'); already  initialized that result should in this div form, so I have to create on more div? and what is the next step?

Comment: @RobertoLinares I fixed my plunk and have added your stuff

Comment: @Anton Roberto probably didn't notice the `var $result = $('#form');` line.  the `.html(...)` line is not likely to be the issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry, now I see in the plunk that the problem is not the append. What you want is to have updatable inputs for the form fields instead of just the data. Is that right?

Comment: @RobertoLinares it's correct, I'm sorry for a late answer, have tried to find solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the HTML you place in the `$result` variable so instead of just showing the data, you place input controls to make it editable.

Also, you need to place a "save changes" button along with the form so you can save the changes made to the form data, either to the server o to your client-side data repository.

[**Edited plunk**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DOJ3uHeMSWqoKX8DPbuJ?p=preview)

Comment: wow! this is exactly what I'm looking for, damn your genius, thank you!

Comment: Could you check my new [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LD3LBGXUFXTwX6XW4FqO?p=preview), I'm trying to set submit button, but my event even doesn't fire