# Primefaces: Select dataTable row via client side API with rowKey instead of rowIndex

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Is there a nice/recommended way to select a row in a [Primefaces dataTable](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml) **via the client side API** if I only know the rowKey but not the rowIndex of that row?

Use case: My JSF/Primefaces page displays a map and a list of areas on that map. When the user clicks on a map area, a JavaScript eventhandler is called and gets the area's unique id (=rowKey). The handler should select the area in the list.

Currently, the event handler contains this code:

```
var clickedTr = $("div[id='DATATABLEFORM:DATATABLEID']").find("tr[data-rk='" + clickedRowKey + "']");
PF('MYDATATABLEWIDGET').selectRow(clickedTr);
```

(where, obviously, you have to replace DATATABLEFORM:DATATABLEID with the form containing the datatable and the datatable's id and MYDATATABLEWIDGET with the datatable's widgetVar).

While this is working, it isn't particularly robust to name/id changes. So: Am I missing something? This sounds like an obvious client API feature - but I can't find it in the docs.

Comment: jquery has the option to return the 'index' in the table rows client side..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery so you can pass that. And no it is not an 'obvious' client API feature since you are the first one to request it in 7 years ;-)

Comment: Interesting! What's the advantage of using the jquery index over using the tr directly (like I do now)?

Comment: If that code is working: none. I thought since you posted this, it failed.

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that's confusing. Edited to clarify this.