# How to find the index of a Sharepoint list/table's 2. page by using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint 2013 list (html table) where I would like to get the row index if I click on a row element. After failing several times by using MouseEvent object I find a quite simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469883/how-to-find-the-index-of-a-row-in-a-table-using-jquery).

So I am using a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("tr").click(function (){
        alert($("tr").index(this));
    });
});
```

This is working well, but if I click on the button to go to the next 30 element of the table it stops working and even if I return to the first page not working anymore. So I have to reload the page to make it works again. What I noticed is that the page is the same, so it is not redirect to a new url, but it gets an addition to the url if I click on the button like: "#InplviewHashea3cdf07-1a28-4a44-bcb2-01f7d45a76c0=Paged%3DTRUE-p_ID%3D340-PageFirstRow%3D31". Sadly I am new to JS so I have no idea how to deal with this. Thanks you very much for any suggestion!

Comment: So you have data in a list and you create an HTML table out of the list? Is this through custom code, ie JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah Sharepoint custom lists are HTML tables. So if u create a custom list in SP u get a HTML table u can freely edit (from the GUI or u can add code too) and add new columns. It have a default limit to show only 30 row and it have a "next" button at the bottom of the page to go to the next 30 element if u press it. I added javascript code to get the rowindex, but it is stops working if I go to the next 30 element.